# How to find class inheritance (dissasembling)

Tags: c++, inheritance, ida

I am trying to find class inheritance from app in IDA, which was compiled in Microsoft Viusal Studio. I have found all constructors of classes and their VMT tables. I found some somewhere that it is easy to find, if there is calling from some constructor another constructor. However there is not any calls from constructors which I found. Is there some other way how to identify class hierarchy parent/child (maybe from VMT tables)?

Comment: I don't see what Vehicle Miles Traveled has to do with inheritance.

Comment: Virtual Method Table

Comment: If RTTI was enabled on the build (usually is) and you have a pointer to the virtual function table you can from that obtain a pointer to the associated type information, decode it (it may not be documented), and determine type associations and multiple inheritance.

Comment: But for non-polymorphic classes, without any virtual, you'll find nothing about inheritance.

Comment: Yeah, RTTI is enabled, I have also information about RTTI class hierarchy